# Calculate the distance between animals that occur within an hour of each other in a large data set

Tags: r, datatable, gps, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance between different animals. The data I have doesn't have the location of all animals at the same time point. I originally calculated the distance to between animals based on the 'nearest' time point I had their location for using the code below

```
library( data.table )
library( sf )
library( geosphere )
library( tidyverse )

DT <- data.table::fread(“  #paste data ")

DT[, datetime := as.POSIXct( paste(Date, Time ), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" ) ]
DT[ , c("lon", "lat") := DT %>% 
      sf::st_as_sf( coords = c("GPS.S", "GPS.E"), crs = 32736 ) %>% 
      sf::st_transform( 4326 ) %>% sf::st_coordinates() %>% data.table::as.data.table() ][]

L <- split( DT, by = "ID" )

lapply( L, function(x) {
  lapply( L, function(y) {
    x[, unique(y$ID) := y[x, x.rowid, roll = "nearest", on = .(datetime)] ]
  })
})

CD <- data.table::rbindlist( L, fill= T )

CD.melt <- data.table::melt(CD, 
                            measure.vars = patterns("Animal 2"), 
                            variable.name = "ID2", 
                            variable.factor = FALSE,
                            value.name = "rowid2" )

CD.melt[ CD, `:=`( lon2 = i.lon, lat2 = i.lat ), on = .(rowid2 = rowid) ][]

CD.melt <- CD.melt %>%
  dplyr::mutate( distance = purrr::pmap( 
    list( a = lon, 
          b = lat, 
          x = lon2,
          y = lat2 ), 
    ~ round( geosphere::distHaversine( c(..1, ..2), c(..3, ..4) ) ) ) )

dcast( CD.melt, rowid + ID + GPS.E + GPS.S + Date + Time ~ ID2, value.var = "distance" )
```

This works fine but I now want to calculate the distance between animals if the time point is within an hour of each other, instead of to the nearest time point. For some of the data there won't be another animal that was seen within the hour, this is fine and can be NA. Any help is very appreciated!

I have included a sample of my data below

```
rowid,ID,GPS.E,GPS.S,Date,Time 
1,Animal 1,417547,393907,2017-01-01,06:19
2,Animal 1,417313,395715,2017-01-01,08:45
3,Animal 1,417769,395000,2017-01-01,16:34
4,Animal 1,418418,394985,2017-01-02,08:18
5,Animal 1,419448,395405,2017-01-02,15:57
6,Animal 1,418249,396145,2017-01-03,07:24
7,Animal 1,417399,396238,2017-01-03,17:44
8,Animal 1,417177,395521,2017-01-03,19:33
9,Animal 1,417320,396119,2017-01-04,06:33
10,Animal 1,417770,396080,2017-01-04,17:01
11,Animal 1,417232,396812,2017-01-05,08:43
12,Animal 1,417716,396745,2017-01-05,16:43
13,Animal 2,416571,396099,2017-01-01,07:30
14,Animal 2,416423,395996,2017-01-01,16:15
15,Animal 2,416184,395916,2017-01-02,08:28
16,Animal 2,416002,395858,2017-01-02,15:34
17,Animal 2,415329,395981,2017-01-02,18:03
18,Animal 2,415454,395993,2017-01-03,09:14
19,Animal 2,415450,397175,2017-01-03,17:27
20,Animal 2,415781,396949,2017-01-04,06:12
21,Animal 2,415702,396949,2017-01-04,17:23
22,Animal 2,415682,395868,2017-01-05,06:19
23,Animal 2,415017,397185,2017-01-05,08:12
24,Animal 2,414516,396990,2017-01-05,16:18
25,Animal 3,418971,394300,2017-01-01,08:59
26,Animal 3,418275,394558,2017-01-01,16:45
27,Animal 3,419881,394940,2017-01-02,08:20
28,Animal 3,416899,396680,2017-01-02,13:01
29,Animal 3,420304,394669,2017-01-02,15:25
30,Animal 3,416614,396713,2017-01-03,05:32
31,Animal 3,419585,394825,2017-01-03,08:20
32,Animal 3,421528,396153,2017-01-03,17:03
33,Animal 3,420045,396510,2017-01-04,06:27
34,Animal 3,419636,396349,2017-01-04,17:17
35,Animal 3,419499,396212,2017-01-05,08:22
36,Animal 3,420515,395898,2017-01-05,16:14
```

Comment: take a look at my answer to your previous question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333029/calculate-the-distance-between-animals-at-different-time-points/66335304#66335304
Take a lok at the rolling join part in the line with the `roll = "nearest"`-part... read (probably a lot) about how data.table roling joins work, and adjust the roll-argument as needed.. good luck :)

Comment: Hi @Wimpel , thank you for your comment, I researched it and if I use `one_hour<- 60*60` and `roll = -one_hour` it seems to match to only the points that occur after the time point. If I use `roll=one_hour` it only matches to the points before, any idea how to get them to match to both?

Comment: you could try to match them to the nearest, and then throw the match away afterwards, if the times are <>1hour of eachother ?

Comment: I just ran the two codes separately in the end and combined the columns, probably not the fastest way of doing it but it works :)